# What are popular automation tools being used today?

Tags: automated-testing, quality-assurance

I have been a manual tester for two years and 6 months. I would like to improve my testing skills using automation. What are the popular tools being used today for beginners?

Comment: Too broad.  There are many.

Comment: Maybe a question like "How can i research the popularity of automation frameworks?" would be better suited. What did you do to research this yourself? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I am a Java/ Android dev and have used the following within the past few months:

- [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) for Java Unit tests
- [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) for Android UI Testing

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html) a link to Android's Testing page. Pretty good info in there. For Android Performance testing, there's this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-perf-testing/index.html#0).

Answer (score 0):

It strongly depends on what applications you would like to test, please find the best free and open source tools compilation:

- Desktop Automation:

  - [Sikuli Script](http://www.sikuli.org/)
  - [ldtp](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)
- Mobile Automation

  - [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/)
  - [Appium](http://appium.io/)
- Web Applications Testing:

  - [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
  - [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)
  - [Watir](http://watir.com/)
- Performance Testing:

  - [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)